# Concatenating arrays or arrays of list to output same data type in python

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation

Consider the following arrays

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.array([1,2,3],dtype='object')
a2 = np.array([["A"],["D"],["R"]],,dtype='object')
a3 = np.array([["A","F"],["D"],["R"]],dtype='object')
```

The following two gives different types of output. Did not expected this. Is this normal?

```
np.c_[a1,a2]

#array([[1, 'A'],
#      [2, 'D'],
#      [3, 'R']], dtype=object)

np.c_[a1,a3]

#array([[1, list(['A', 'F'])],
#      [2, list(['D'])],
#      [3, list(['R'])]], dtype=object)
```

Why the first works and not the second expression? I do not see any difference between `a2` and `a3`. Further, which concatenation method (c_, stack, concatenation) would output the same type of output without having to add other lines of code such as checking the output data type and converting it as needed.

```
np.concatenate((a1,a2),axis=0) # Error: ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

np.concatenate((a1,a3),axis=0) # works
#array([1, 2, 3, list(['A', 'F']), list(['D']), list(['R'])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Numpy really isn't designed around working with arrays of list objects. Why are you using this?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what do you suggest for this kind of operations. I need to append a1 and a2 sidewise.

Comment: What common behavior are you expecting? Look at `a2` and `a3`.  They are very different.

Comment: You should just be using python lists. Why use numpy?

Answer (score 1):

That actually makes sense, see the types of each one of the arrays:

```
a1 = np.array([1,2,3],dtype='object') => 1D array of objects, size 3
a2 = np.array([["A"],["D"],["R"]],,dtype='object') => 2D array of objects, size 3x1
a3 = np.array([["A","F"],["D"],["R"]],dtype='object') => 1D array of lists of objects
```

`a3` is an array of lists, as np 2d (or more-d) arrays are matrices, you cant have 1 row with the size of 1, and the second in the size of 3, much of np computational efficiency is due to the way the arrays are organized in the memory.

So numpy interprets `np.array([["A","F"],["D"],["R"]],dtype='object')` as an array of lists (which are also, objects).
Attempting this with a different type, will results in error:

```
np.array([[1,2],[3],[4]],dtype=np.int64) -->
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Therefor `np.concatenate((a1,a2),axis=0)` fails as a1 is of shape `(3,)` and a2 is of shape `(3,1)`, while a1 and a3 are both `(3,)`.

You could solve it by:

```
np.concatenate((a1,np.reshape(a2,a1.shape)))
np.concatenate((np.reshape(a1,a2.shape),a2))
```

Both are valid, each has different results, there is no 1 solution, as the concatenation between `a1` and `a2` is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

From the [numpy doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html): ***In particular, arrays will be stacked along their last axis after being upgraded to at least 2-D with 1’s post-pended to the shape (column vectors made out of 1-D arrays).*** This means `np.c_` will first converts a 1D array to 2D array and then concatenate along the second axis. Here is what happens:

In case of `np.c_[a1,a2]`:

1. convert `a1` to `[[1],[2],[3]]`
2. stack `[[1],[2],[3]]` to `[["A"],["D"],["R"]]` along second axis result in:

   ```
   [[1 'A']
    [2 'D']
    [3 'R']]
   ```

In case of `np.c_[a1,a3]`:

1. convert `a1` to `[[1],[2],[3]]`
2. Tries to stack `[[1],[2],[3]]` to `[["A","F"],["D"],["R"]]` along the second axis. However, numpy arrays have to be rectangular and `a3` is not. The alternative is to interpret each list as single item and stack like following to make the array rectangular shape (3,2):

   ```
   [[1 list(['A', 'F'])]
    [2 list(['D'])]
    [3 list(['R'])]]
   ```

Depending on how you would like the output be, there are different ways. If you want to simply concatenate a mix of 1D/2D arrays into 1D, you can first `squeeze` them (remove dimension with size 1) and concatenate like this:

```
np.concatenate((np.squeeze(a1),np.squeeze(a2)),axis=0)
#[1 2 3 'A' 'D' 'R']
np.concatenate((np.squeeze(a1),np.squeeze(a3)),axis=0)
#[1 2 3 list(['A', 'F']) list(['D']) list(['R'])]
```

You can also `hstack` them to concatenate the contents of all inside lists:

```
np.concatenate((np.hstack(a1),np.hstack(a2)),axis=0)
#[1 2 3 'A' 'D' 'R']
np.concatenate((np.hstack(a1),np.hstack(a3)),axis=0)
#['1' '2' '3' 'A' 'F' 'D' 'R']
```